Row Update in Google Sheets using AppSheets
I'm creating a fairly simple check-in App that is running off Google Sheets. The Google Sheet is a customer information sheet with the following columns
SubGUID
FirstName
MiddleName
LastName
Present (True or False)
QRCodes
All the above columns have been filled where the SubGUID is unique and the QR Codes with the SubGUID embedded in them.
For the Present column I have a drop-down with the only 2 options as TRUE or FALSE
I also have conditional formatting where the row is coloured either Green or Red based on True or False in the Present column respectively.
Now for the App, I want to be able to scan the QR Code and it will update the Present column to TRUE if there is a match which in turn will turn the Row green and I can see how many people have checked-in.
I have created the Google Sheets with everything populated. The name of the sheet is Customer Information
In Appsheet, I created a new app using existing data from the Google Sheets.
Under Data --> Tables, I see my table and the Updates, Adds are checked and everything else is the default.
For columns I see all my columns and 2 auto-generated columns called _RowNumber and _ComputedName.
These are the settings for the columns in the same order as they appear in the Data --> Columns tab



NAME
TYPE
KEY?
LABEL?
FORMULA
SHOW?
EDITABLE?
REQUIRE?
INITIAL VALUE
DISPLAY NAME
DESCRIPTION
SEARCH?
SCAN?
NFC?
PII?




_RowNumber
Number








Number of this row






SubGUID
Text
-
-

-
-
-
UNIQUEID()


-
-




FirstName
Name



-

-



-


-


MiddleName
Name



-





-


-


LastName
Name



-

-



-


-


Present
Enum



-
-
-



-





QRCodes
Url















_ComputedName
Name


CONCATENATE([FirstName]," ",[MiddleName]," ",[LastName])













I went ahead and created a new view under UX --> Views

For this data : Customer Information (Sheet Name)

View type : Form

Position : Middle


View Options

Row key : (blank)

Page style : Automatic

Form style : Automatic

Column order : Automatic (I see SubGUID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Present)

Save/cancel position : Bottom

Max. nested rows : 5

Auto save : selected

Auto re-open : selected

Finish view : Auto assign (Go Back)


The rest of the stuff is default.
Now on the mobile preview that I see, I only see the SubGUID and Present fields
Mobile Preview
When I switch over to the desktop preview, I see all the fields that I defined to show
Desktop Preview
Why isn't the mobile preview showing the other columns as the desktop?
Also when I scan the SubGUID and select TRUE for present and try to save it, I get the error "There is already a row with the key: <SubGUID>"
SubGUID error
I created a new Action under Behavior --> Action
Action Name : Update Attendance
For a record of this table : Customer Information (Google Sheet name)
Do this : Data: set the values of some columns in this row
Set these columns : Present : "TRUE"
Everything else remains default for Actions
Actions Settings
In UX --> Views --> Behavior under Event Actions on Form Saved I select the Action that I just created.
Attaching Action to Behavior
After all this, I can't scan and mark a user present in the Google Sheet.
I keep getting the same error of a row with the key exists even though under actions I tell it to update a column in the row instead of adding another row.
How can I make my App function so that I can scan the QR Code and then select TRUE and save the record which in turn will switch the present flag to TRUE and turn the Google Sheet Green?
Please let me know if you have any other questions?
